# Label must be a simple identifier?? Flash/Flex Builder

Tags: syntax, flash-builder, selecteditem

I have this code:

```
public function chooseCategoryDDL_changeHandler(event:IndexChangeEvent):void {

       var para:Object = new Object();
           para.action = "changecategoryxml";
           para.book_class = event:IndexChangeEvent.book_class;

           if (event.IndexChangeEvent > -1 ) {
           changeCategory.send(para);
           }
```

I keep getting the error message that, 'Label must be a simple identifier'. Ideally, i'm wanting to write the code to state:

```
 ... para.book_class = event.selectedItem.book_class;

           if (event.selectedItem > -1 ) {
           changeCategory.send(para);
           }
```

Though, when I try and use the selectedItem syntax, it gives me an 'Access to undefined property selectedItem'. I'm really tearing my hair out about this and it's been bugging me for ages. If anyone can please shed any light on this I will be eternally grateful :)

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

I had the same error from a dumb typo : some line was terminated by ':' instead of ';'
For the visually impaired (like me), that's colon instead of semicolon.

Comment: Many Thanks! you saved me a lot of time with this today

Answer (score 0):

I didn't really read this, but the syntax of this line looks invalid:
para.book_class = event:IndexChangeEvent.book_class;

Use a dot maybe?

para.book_class = event.IndexChangeEvent.book_class;